# Proper way to specify indices in Direct3D

Tags: c++, 3d, directx

Suppose I want to render a pyramid in Direct3D. I have the following vertices in my vertex buffer:

```
Vertex vertices[] = {
    {XMFLOAT3(+1.0f,0.0f,+1.0f),(const float*)&Colors::Green},
    {XMFLOAT3(+1.0f,0.0f,-1.0f),(const float*)&Colors::Green},
    {XMFLOAT3(-1.0f,0.0f,-1.0f),(const float*)&Colors::Green},
    {XMFLOAT3(-1.0f,0.0f,+1.0f),(const float*)&Colors::Green},
    {XMFLOAT3(0.0f,1.5f,0.0f),(const float*)&Colors::Blue}
 }
```

Where Vertex is a simple `struct` with a position and color value.

Now in my index buffer, what is the proper order to specify these vertices to draw the pyramid so all of its triangles are front facing? Whenever I try what seems logical to me, I end up with some triangles drawn facing the wrong way.

Comment: If all triangles were front facing, it wouldn't be a pyramid ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I usually did this:

- draw your model on a piece of paper, in 3d mesh editor, or just [Google up an image](https://www.google.com/search?q=pyramid%20vertices%20indices&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=tbO1UtL0FKOR0AX094HwDA&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1413&bih=959)
- divide non-triangles (such as square in a base of pyramid) to triangles
- assign consecutive numbers and write them near each vertex
- start indexing from front-faced, visible triangles in order, depending on what renderer expects (for example, in clockwise order)
- then index triangles that are back-faced in opposite order (counterclockwise in our example) -- or -- mentally rotate mesh to 180 degree (or mentally rotate yourself around it), "look at it's back side" and index triangles in straight order (clockwise).

As alternatives:

- get 3d mesh editor, draw you model, save in any text format (.obj for example), open it with text editor and find index data
- [Google for it](http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~reckert/460/3dpoly.htm)

Surely, your renderer and, especially, input assembler's primitive type (such as triangle list or triangle strip) and culling must be properly set up to draw model in a right way.

Hope it helps!